# Background-color vertical 50% split does not work when the footer is positioned with flex-box

Tags: html, css

I would like to display the background of a website in two colors. Green at the top and grey at the bottom. The separation should be at ~50%. I have given the main tag a height of 50vh and the background-color: green. I have given the body the background-color: gray. That worked quite well so far.

But now I wanted to position the footer with flex-box at the bottom. But that would destroy my background-color-50%-split, because I have to stretch (`flex:1`). How can I still make such a background color split? It **should not** be static.

**Without flex-box split:**

```css
:root {
  --header-height: 42px;
  --container-width: 900px;
  --bg-dark-primary: #333;
  --bg-dark-secondary: gray;
  --text-color-primary: #333;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--bg-dark-secondary);
  color: var(--text-color-primary);
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;  
  background: var(--bg-dark-primary);
}

footer {
  max-height:200px;
  min-height:50px; 
  background:black; 
  color: white;
}
.container {
  max-width: var(--container-width);
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {  
  display:inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: var(--header-height);
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

main {
  margin-top: var(--header-height);
  height: calc(55vh - var(--header-height));
  color: white;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container header">
    
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="logo__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40">
      <span class="logo__brand">brand</span>
    </div>
    
    <nav class="navbar">  

    </nav>    
  </div><!-- container header -->
</header>

<main>
  <div>x</div>
</main>

<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

**With flex-box to position footer**

```css
:root {
  --header-height: 42px;
  --container-width: 900px;
  --bg-dark-primary: #333;
  --bg-dark-secondary: gray;
  --text-color-primary: #333;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--bg-dark-secondary);
  color: var(--text-color-primary);
  min-height: 100vh;
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:column;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;  
  background: var(--bg-dark-primary);
}

footer {
  max-height:200px;
  min-height:50px; 
  background:black; 
  color: white;
}
.container {
  max-width: var(--container-width);
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {  
  display:inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: var(--header-height);
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: var(--header-height);
  /*height: calc(55vh - var(--header-height));*/
  color: white;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container header">
    
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="logo__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40">
      <span class="logo__brand">brand</span>
    </div>
    
    <nav class="navbar">  

    </nav>    
  </div><!-- container header -->
</header>

<main>
  <div>x</div>
</main>

<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Use a 'to bottom' `linear-gradient` with two colors as background image.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** in full

In my initial answer I did not address the 'scolling' background requirement and created a solution with a 'fixed' background. Here's the correction...

It is easy enough to create a two-color linear gradient and use that as a `background-image` for any container element you require. As you are obviously accustomed to use *CSS custom variables* I created a variable holding a vertical gradient with only `green` and `#333`:

```css
--gradient: linear-gradient(to bottom,green 0% 50vh,#333 50vh 100%)
```

- `green 0% 50vh` fills the upper half of the viewport
- `#333 50vh 100%` fills the remainder of the element, no matter how tall it gets.

(**Notice** the mixed use of `%` and `vh` to create the effect)

Make sure it fills the entire background of the container element concerned using the proper `background-size`. For this solution `cover` works fine.

I created a four page demo (each `min-height: 100vh`) following your main *Flexbox Layout* page structure without the *custom variables* and alignments.

- I added `body { justify-content: space-between }`, which forces `header` and `footer` to the top and bottom of `<body>` because of the use of `main { flex: 1 }`.

As an extra I introduced *custom attributes* `[bg]` and `[headfoot]` to try alternative solutions, both used in `<body>`:

**[bg]** options

- 'scroll', `background-attachement: scroll` (default HTML) as required by OP.
- 'fixed', `background-attachement: fixed` as in my previous answer.

**[headfoot]** options

- 'scroll', both `<header>` and `<footer>` scroll out of view not being 'fixed' to the viewport (HTML default `position: static`).
- 'head', `<header>` is fixed to the top of the viewport.
- 'foot', `<footer>` is fixed to the bottom of the viewport
- 'fixed', both `<header>` and `<footer>` are fixed to their respective side of the viewport

Lastly, to remove the 'rainbow' and 'inverted grey/green' background simply delete `bg rainbow` and `bg last` from their respective `<div class="...">`. They are just there to show some alternative uses.

The code is commented and should be self-explanatory:

```css
/*************************/
/* Main background setup */
/*************************/

:root {
     /* define two color gradients: green/gray and gray/green */
     --gradient1: linear-gradient(to bottom, green 0% 50vh, #333  50vh 100%);
     --gradient2: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333  0% 50% , green 50%  100%);
}

/* To toy with background attachment options, set in <body> */
body[bg="fixed"] { --attachment: fixed }

.bg {
    /* Use background and blend-mode variables */
    background-image     : var(--background, none);  /* with fallbacks */
    background-blend-mode: var(--blend-mode, normal);
    background-size      : cover;
    background-repeat    : no-repeat;

    background-attachment: var(--attachment, scroll); /* with fallback */
    /*
        big difference 'background-attachment' en/disabled
        with multipage content and varying backgrounds...
    */
}
.bg.green {
    /* Attach to background variable */
    --background: var(--gradient1);
    /* No blend-mode required */
}
.bg.last {
    --background: var(--gradient2);
}

/*****************************************************/
/* Just fun: fixed background image/gradient overlay */
/*****************************************************/
:root {
    /* define another custom background */
     --rainbow: linear-gradient(
                    60deg, 
                    aqua   , #00bcff, #007aff,
                    #0037ff, #0b00ff, #4e00ff,
                    #9000ff, #d300ff, #ff00e9,
                    #ff00a6, #ff0064, #ff0021,
                    #ff2100, #ff6400, #ffa600,
                    #ffe900, #d3ff00, #90ff00,
                    #4eff00, #0bff00, #00ff37,
                    #00ff7a, #00ffbc, aqua
                );

    --image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/281/1920/1200");
}

.bg.rainbow {
    /* Attach image and gradient to background variable */
    --background: var(--image), var(--rainbow);

    /* Define their background blending modes */
    --blend-mode: multiply, screen;
}


/****************************************/
/* Demo page setup, not too interesting */
/****************************************/
*, ::before, ::after { box-sizing: border-box }

body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%; min-height: 100vh;

    display: flex; flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* moves <footer> to end of <body> when it's not 'fixed' */
    
    line-height: 1.5; color: White;
}
p {
    padding: 3rem; max-width: 75%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border: 1px solid Gray;
}
a { color: inherit }

/* Demo fill viewport/parent to simulate a 'page' */
.fullpage {
    /* easy centering of content */
    display: grid; place-items: center;
    width: 100%; min-height: 100vh;
}
/* Header and footer height */
:root { --headfoot: 3.5rem }

main {
    flex: 1; min-height: 100vh;
}

header, footer {
    display: grid; place-items: center;
    opacity: 0.7; /* for debugging */

    height: var(--headfoot); width: 100%;
    background-color: black; color: white;
}

/*
    To toy with header/footer viewport attachement, set in <body>

    options: 'scoll' - header/footer not fixed to viewport (default)
             'head'  - only header fixed to viewport
             'foot'  - only footer fixed to viewport
             'fixed' - header/footer both fixed to viewport

    Without [headfoot] attribute behavior defaults to HTML default
*/
body:is(:not([headfoot]),[headfoot="scroll"],[headfoot=""]) { position: static; z-index: auto }
body:is([headfoot="head"],[headfoot="fixed"])>header { position: fixed; z-index: 1; top   : 0 }
body:is([headfoot="foot"],[headfoot="fixed"])>footer { position: fixed; z-index: 1; bottom: 0 }
```

```html
<!-- <body> contains the main page background -->
<body class="bg green" headfoot="scroll" bg="scroll">
    <header>some header</header>
    <main>
        <div class="fullpage">
            <p>
                The &lt;body&gt; background image is a fixed two-color gradient.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="fullpage">
            <p>This &lt;div&gt; has no background, so the &lt;body&gt; background is visible.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Overlays the <body> background -->
        <div class="fullpage bg rainbow">
            <p>
                This &lt;div&gt; overrides the fixed two-color gradient with a gradient overlayed image.<br>
                Image Credit: <a target="_blank" href="https://unsplash.com/photos/_poRbNNfcE8">Victor Erixon, Unsplash</a>
                retrieved via <a target="_blank" href="https://picsum.photos/images">Lorem Picsum, photo id: #281</a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="fullpage bg last">
            <p>This &lt;div&gt; too has no background showing the original background again.</p>
        </div>
    </main>
 
    <footer>some footer</footer>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thank you Rene! This is really great work that you have done. I'll definitely give you a +1up for that. However, the background should not be fixed. That means if you scroll down, the upper green area disappears. Anyway. I think your solution is beautiful!

Comment: I tried to assign `margin-top: calc(45vh - var(--header-height) + 50px);` to footer but this solution works not so well but it shows what i want.

Comment: @MaxPattern  Sorry, I missed the 'static' part. In that case, don't use `background-attachement: fixed` and change the gradient to `--gradient: linear-gradient(to bottom, green 0% 50vh, #333  50vh 100%)`. **Notice** the mixed use of `vh` and `%`, as in: use half the viewport for green and stretch grey to 100% of the element height. I will adjust my answer later today. This solution doesn't work out of the box with what I had posted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and time. I will show my appreciation ...

Answer (score 1):

You can put the green background as a kind of cover over the darker background. But then you have to work with position absolute and z-index. I personally have nothing against positioning. But I had heard before that it should always be the last choice. Which I personally don't find. Without these CSS elements we would be a lot poorer in web design ;-)

**Here is an example of how you can implement it:**

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height: 100vh;
}

header, footer {
  background: black;
  min-height: 80px;
  color: white;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:30px;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  z-index: -3;
}

article {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200vh;
}

.blender {
  z-index: -2;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    HEADER
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="blender"></div>
    <article>
      MAIN
    </article>    
  </main>

  <footer>
    FOOTER
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Maik! The problem what i have when i will use your solution, that z-index for the main tag will disable my input fields. It is not possible to enter in form elements between the main tag. Only when i remove the z-index then i can enter the form elements. Did you know why?